# Mapping data to a corresponding property order

Tags: c#, automapper

I have to read several excel tables into classes using a PropertyOrderAttribute

```
    [PropertyOrder(2)]
    public string B { get; set; }
    [PropertyOrder(1)]
    public string A { get; set; }
```

Following "hand-written" Mapper does the job:

```
    public static void MapByOrder<T, U>(T aObject, int aOrder, U aValue)
    {
        foreach (var p in aObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var pm = p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(PropertyOrderAttribute));
            if (pm != null && (pm as PropertyOrderAttribute).Order == aOrder && p.PropertyType == typeof(U))
                p.SetValue(aObject, aValue);
        }
    }
```

I am wondering, if a mapper tool like automapper can also resolve this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AutoMapper to map objects by order defined in the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748996/how-to-use-automapper-to-map-objects-by-order-defined-in-the-class)

Comment: Do both the Source type and the Destination type have the `PropertyOrder` attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way of mapping based on the order of properties.  However, you could create an `ITypeConverter` that uses the `PropertyOrder` attribute (or some other deterministic way of finding the correct ordering) to map between types.  Here's a simple example, you could potentially make the destination type generic if you need to map to multiple destination types:

```
class PropertyOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly int order;

    public PropertyOrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public int Order => order;
}

class Ordered
{
    [PropertyOrder(3)]
    public int A { get; set; }
    [PropertyOrder(1)]
    public string B { get; set; }
    [PropertyOrder(2)]
    public DateTime C { get; set; }
}

class Spreadsheet
{
    public object[] Cells { get; set; }
}

class OrderedConverter : ITypeConverter<Spreadsheet, Ordered>
{
    public Ordered Convert(Spreadsheet source, Ordered destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var properties = typeof(Ordered).GetProperties()
            .Where(property => Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(PropertyOrderAttribute)))
            .Select(property => new { Attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PropertyOrderAttribute), true).OfType<PropertyOrderAttribute>().Single(), Property = property })
            .OrderBy(orderdProperty => orderdProperty.Attribute.Order)
            .ToArray();

        if (destination == null)
        {
            destination = new Ordered();
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < source.Cells; i += 0)
        {
            properties[i].Property.SetValue(destination, source.Cells[i]);
        }

        return destination;
    }
}

AutoMapper.Mapper
    .CreateMap<Spreadsheet, Ordered>()
    .ConvertUsing(new OrderedConverter());
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i was looking for - never had the spreadsheet as source class in mind...